# get_bloginfo() not echo on footer - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey i am using this code to echo site Title in footer, but not echo.

**Code - >**

```
   add_action( 'genesis_footer', 'custom_footer_copyright' );
function custom_footer_copyright() { 
    $blog = get_bloginfo('name');
    $creds = "<a href="/">".$blog."</a>";
    echo "<div class='copyright'>$creds</div>";
}
```

### no tutorial found about this problem

Updated Section -

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class', 1 );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ((is_home() && !is_front_page()) || (is_search()) || is_tag() || is_author()) {
        $classes[] = 'archive';
    }
    if (is_singular('page') || is_404() || (is_search() && 0 === $wp_query->found_posts )) {
        $classes[] = 'single';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not echo"?  the code looks fine. Are you sure the template file actually gets rendered?

Comment: nope i am not sure about this

Comment: not using it on template file. i am using it in wp_footer function

Comment: can you show other pieces of code?

Comment: check the updated code

Comment: in which file have you pasted that piece of code? and are you. 100% that the genesis_footer action actually gets called in your footer file?

Comment: it is functions.php and if i put some text in this code it echo on footer and site url, current year also outputtted to footer but not the bloginfo(name)

Comment: @Diego any info there ?

Comment: at this point are you sure that blog name actually has a value on your db? does the rest of the output (div class copyright..) actually exist?

Comment: yup. copyright div exists. but not sure about db. have to check

Comment: did you know about wordpress ? i want to add body class to only search-no-results but it is not working....check the updated code.

Comment: here is the link [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68618660/how-to-add-seperate-classes-to-no-search-result-and-found-search-result-pages-on)