# How to add seperate classes to no-search-result and found-search-result pages on wordrpess search - is_search()

Tags: php, wordpress, class, wordpress-shortcode

I want to add seperate body classes for no search result and found search result pages on wordrpess search.

I used that code but it isn't working - > what's the error here and what is the solution

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class', 1 ); function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if ((is_home() && !is_front_page()) || (is_search()) || is_tag() || is_author()) {
        $classes[] = 'archive';
    }
    if (is_singular('page') || is_404() || (is_search() && 0 === $wp_query->found_posts )) {
        $classes[] = 'single';
    }
    return $classes; }
```

I am unable to get it work

Comment: no answer there ?//

Comment: please help me..

Answer (score 0):

that's an old one.. in case you do not have the answer or to help others too

You need the global variable `$post`

```
function custom_body_classes( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    //var_dump($post);

    if ( is_search() ) {
        if($post) { //means that you have search results
            $classes[] = 'class-results-found';
        }
        else { //no results found
            $classes[] = 'class-no-results-found';
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_body_classes' );
```

if this is the answer you are looking for, please accept it. Otherwise, give more details of what you are trying to accomplish